# Как использовать system(wmic) в DLL?

Tags: c++, winapi

Пишу первую DLL (учусь), и вопрос, как использовать эту функцию?

```
system("wmic path win32_physicalmedia get SerialNumber");
```

мне нужно вывести в консоль ид жёсткого диска

Comment: Наверное вам стоит использовать WinAPI. Вот похожий вопрос https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7aed0ee5-c3ec-401c-8cd6-6cd44ffabc45/retreive-the-hard-drive-serial-number-through-winapi?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: использование system(...) - не лучшее решение. в winapi есть функция [GetVolumeInformation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getvolumeinformationa), она вам подойдет. если не разберетесь - свистите!

Comment: @acade как подключить winapi скажите пожалуйста :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#include <Windows.h> // здесь хранятся объявления функций WinApi
#include <iostream>  // std::cout

int main()
{
    char lpDriveLabel[30]{}; // сюда запишем метку диска
    char lpDriveFs[30]{};    // сюда запишем файловую систему (FAT32, NTFS...)
    DWORD nDriveSerialNum = 0; // серийный номер диска
    DWORD nDriveLabelSize = sizeof(lpDriveLabel); // размер буфера
    GetVolumeInformationA( // WinApi функция, дающая ин-цию о диске
        "c:/",             // путь к необходимому диску
        lpDriveLabel,     // буфер для хранения метки диска
        sizeof(lpDriveLabel), // размер буфера для метки
        &nDriveSerialNum,     // адрес переменной, куда записать ин-цию о серийном ном.
        &nDriveLabelSize,     // адрес переменной, где хранится размер буфера
        NULL,                  // какие-то флаги (нам неважно)
        lpDriveFs,             // буфер для хранения названия файловой системы диска
        sizeof(lpDriveFs)      // размер буфера для файловой системы
    );
    std::cout << "Серийный номер диска C: " << nDriveSerialNum << "\n"; // вывод в консоль
};
```

После этого будете выводить на экран значение переменной `nDriveSerialNum` - это и есть серийный номер диска.

Comment: error C2601: lpDriveLabel: недопустимые локальные определения функций
Пытался самостоятельно решить эту проблему и никак.
Пишу плагин для SA:MP сервера
занёс это в:
cell AMX_NATIVE_CALL Test(AMX* amx, cell* params)

Comment: @Kronka, с скобками нигде не напутал?

Comment: вопрос этот решил, убрал фигурные скобки, а теперь последнее: как вывести значение nDriveSerialNum ?

Comment: @Kronka, обновил ответ, смотрите

Comment: а как это же значение получить через CMD используя wmic ?

Comment: @Kronka, `wmic diskdrive get serialnumber` или из кода `system("wmic diskdrive get serialnumber")`. Замечание: он покажет серийный номер в 16-ричной системе счисления